# Adding Windows Phone 8 SDK to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm on a really bad internet connection, and I have Windows Phone 8 SDK files, but no the install file. Is there a way to add Windows 8 SDK to Visual Studio, without downloading the install file?

Comment: Please Don't Modify this question. i want to ask this.. if any suggestion replay me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure, what you mean? You need either existing Visual Studio 2012 installation + you have to install WP8 SDK which expands the Visual Studio, or you can only download the SDK, install it and use the Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone.
Either way you have to download the SDK, either online installation file here:
https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk
Or complete offline installation ISO here:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=257234&clcid=0x409

Comment: Has second link of ISO file worked for anyone? It gives me really weared error message, each time I try to install. I could see Windows Phone 8 SDK in Add/Remove programs in control panel. But installation gets failed. Is there an alternative for online SDK installation?

Comment: @Manoj Alternative online SDK installation can be found at the link #1 above or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363)

Comment: @Hoang Thanks. Link that you have provided is for Windows 8. It should not work for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: can you give me the link of visual studio 2012 express for windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also play use the /layout option to dowload locally all the packages, i.e. type

```
WPexpress_full.exe /layout
```

at any command prompt. It will ask for a download folder to save the bits. The ISO is a bit useless, as Phone development leans using a real OS, instead of a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Giulio, An ISO is never useless. ISOs have quite a few benefits, and their one drawback (have to be mounted to use) is simply mitigated. I'm responding here as you're MS staff and perpetrating that myth is frustrating for those in the field.

An ISO is a single file which I can hash to ensure a copy from external media (usb drive, over a network etc.) is successful. An ISO means that I can more easily get files onto a machine that is network isolated. 

I intend to do WP8 dev under Parallels on a Mac, and know of several devs doing the same, so your point about VMs is also a little off base.

Comment: Mine was a quick comment on the specific case: Phone 8 development on Win8 physical machine; I never intended to downplay ISO usage in general cases. E.g. my personal library contains almost 200GB of ISO images I routinely use to build VMs.
My customers are mostly enterprises and your scenario (VM running on a Max) is still uncommon.

Comment: I want to add a second explanation.
I am in a field just like you, so I understand the annoiance of not having the bits in the way I like more. My experience with product group, and Developer Division in particoular, says that there are always good reasons for choosing a specific packaging; we have distribution packages that dependes on other packages and "web" installers are often the best choice.