# Install SDK windows phone 8.0 on VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, sdk

I have a problem trying to install SDK windows phone 8.0 on VS 2012. I installed it but in vs 2012 I can't create a windows phone project. I already tried to unnistall the sdk and reinstall it after but nothing change. Is there a way to make notice to vs 2012 that i have the SDK ? When I install the SDK, the path is Microsoft visual studio 11.0

Thanks

Comment: Could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313080/adding-windows-phone-8-sdk-to-visual-studio-2012?rq=1

Comment: I'have already watch this link, and it does not really help. Exept maybe for changing the installation folder of the sdk but I don't know where I could change it.

Comment: I install visual studio 2012 profesional (it was ultimate before) but without success :(